how to implement flutter video cast to TV
I'm using flutter_vlc_player to cast a video to a device, but I'm encountering an issue where it says "device not found." Here's the code snippet where I attempt to get renderer devices and cast to them:
Future<void> _getRendererDevices() async {
    final castDevices = await controller.getRendererDevices();
    //
    if (castDevices.isNotEmpty) {
      if (!mounted) return;
      final selectedCastDeviceName = await showDialog<String>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Display Devices'),
            content: SizedBox(
              width: double.maxFinite,
              height: 250,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: castDevices.keys.length + 1,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      index < castDevices.keys.length
                          ? castDevices.values.elementAt(index)
                          : 'Disconnect',
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(
                        context,
                        index < castDevices.keys.length
                            ? castDevices.keys.elementAt(index)
                            : null,
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
      if (selectedCastDeviceName != null) {
        await controller.castToRenderer(selectedCastDeviceName);
      }
    } else {
      if (!mounted) return;
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('No Display Device Found!')),
      );
    }}

I expected this code to display a list of available devices and allow me to cast the video. However, I'm getting a "No Display Device Found!" message.
Could someone please suggest alternative solutions for video casting in Flutter, or help troubleshoot why flutter_vlc_player might not be detecting devices correctly?

any one can help me for this
